# Supervisor не может найти conda при запуске очередей через Horizon

Tags: laravel, очередь, supervisord, conda

Проект `Laravel` развернут на `Docker`-контейнерах. В контейнере с `Apache` установлен `supervisor`, который запускает `php artisan horizon`:

```
[program:horizon]
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=php /var/www/html/artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/horizon.log
```

Помимо этого в контейнере установлен пакет миниконда. 
При поднимании контейнера запускаю supervisor и он начинает ждать заданий для очереди. Код очереди представляет собой следующее:

```
public function handle()
{
    $command = escapeshellcmd("conda -V");
    $output = exec($command);
    info([$command,$output]);
    return ([[$command,$output]]);
}
```

При таком раскладе в лог летит информация: `sh: 1: conda: not found`

Однако если выполнить в контейнере `conda -V`, то он выдает версию: `conda 4.5.11`. 
Также заметил странность в контейнере развернут python 3.6, но если вывести в обработчике вместо `"conda -V"` - `"pyton --version"` он выдает `2.7`.
Если запускать `horizon` без `supervisor` через `php artisan horizon` прямо в контейнере, то все отрабатывает корректно и выводит версию конды.
Если заменить `horizon` обычным `queue:work`, то результат аналогичный. Через супервизор не работает, но работает напрямую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в переменных среды отредактировал конфиг supervisor следующим образом и все заработало.

```
[program:horizon]
process_name=%(program_name)s
environment =
     PATH = /opt/conda/bin:/opt/conda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
command=php /var/www/html/artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/horizon.log
```